# Plotting Realtime Graph in visual studio c++

Tags: c#, c++

I am a new to windows programming. I am developing a application to process the measurement data from a laser sensor. I have got the data from the sensor and did some calulations and I need to plot the data which are in the double arrays say afx[81] and afy[81].. I have been browsing since yesterday to plot the 2-D graph.I found out the options I have are,

1. using a third party library like gnuplot.
2. using standard graphic library like PGL. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1546/Plot-Graphic-Library
3. using C# or visual basic to do the plot and using it from c++.

My requirements are

1. I need to do real time plotting.the max scanning frequency of the sensor is 50hz.
2. I want the application to run in all windows computers as a single application.

Can someone provide me the best possible solution that I can approach.

Comment: Presumably afx[n] and afy[n] are the x and y coordinates of a particular point? Do you want those connected by a line, or do you just want a dot (or whatever) at each of those points? How do you receive data from your sensor? A network connection? Or do you already have code to handle that part?

Comment: thx for replying..I want it to be connected by line.. just like a graph..for sensor, I use Ethernet connection. I already have code for that from the manufacturer.

Comment: You might want to look into using [Labview](http://www.ni.com/labview/). It has several types of plots that are intended to visualize real-time data. The laser manufacturer might even already supply a Labview driver/toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be to just use Windows' graphics functions. I'd use `MoveTo` (or [`MoveToEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145069.aspx)) to move to the first point, and then [`LineTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145029.aspx) to draw lines to the subsequent points. Another possibility that might be slightly more efficient would be to use [`Polyline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162815.aspx) instead (but with only 81 points, the gain from this will probably be pretty minimal).

Answer (score 0):

Well, Visual Basic is a good chose if you want a simple plot.

If you want a professional plot suitable for publication use a 3rd party software where you have control over the legend's, axis's and title's font, size color and position.

If you need to fit the data to curves and get the expected value of the parameters and their standard deviations along with the chi-square values I would recommend something like Origin's Lab software. That program has about 100 different built-in functions one can fit to and does multiple y-axis plotting.

Comment: Is that software a C++ library or a stand alone app?